# Proving extension given by Hahn-Banach theorem is not generally unique

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification

I tried to do the following exercise:

> Show that the extension given in the Hahn-Banach theorem is not always unique.

My example was $g: A \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x_1, 0) = x_1$, where $A$ is the $x$-axis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $p(a, b) = |a| + 3|b|$. Clearly $g(x) \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in A$ and $p$ is sublinear. And the functions $f_1 : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f_2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_1(a, b) = a + b$ and $f_2(a, b) = a + 2b$ are both linear, extend $g$ and satisfy $f_1(x) \leq p(x)$, $f_2(x) \leq p(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

The reason I'm asking this question is because I looked up other examples in this site and all the ones I found were much more complicated. Is there anything wrong with my example?

**EDIT:** I realized things might be a bit subtler than this. I don't know what the Hahn-Banach extension of $g$ will be... but I know it's linear so it's of the form $f(a, b) = a + b f(e_2)$. So let $p$ be the sublinear function given by $p(a, b) = |a| + c|b|$ where $c = |f(e_2)| + 1$, a constant. Now, $f$ is dominated by $p$ and another extension could be $f_2(a, b) = a + \frac{c}{2} b$. Is that correct or was the original thing just fine?

Comment: In the Hahn-Banach Theorem the extension $f$ of $g$ satisfies $\|f\|=\|g\|.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I don't think that's completely true. Yes, a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem is that it's possible to find an extension that preserves the norm, but the Hahn-Banach theorem itself only garantees the existence of an extension that is still dominated by the same function that dominates the original function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two examples are fine. But you are making some circular arguments the the EDIT. It doesn't make sense to make $p$ dependent on the extension $f$.